# MVC: Use Display name as column header with CSVHelper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, csvhelper

I have an MVC application where I am using CsvHelper in order to allow the user to export report data in excel. I would like to change the value of some of the column headers on the exported file. In the report model i have defined the the properties like so

```
    public string DateSection1Finished { get; set; }
    public string TimeSection1Finished { get; set; }
    public string DateSection2Finished { get; set; }
    public string TimeSection2Finished { get; set; }
```

Excel example of current output

[image]

Now if i change the value of the property and update all references in my code base i am able to see the column header name be update in the excel document. However, i was wondering if it is possible to use an attribute above the property and map that to the header valuein the excel file output

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Display(Name = "NewColumnHeaderName")]
public string DateSection1Finished { get; set; }
```

Excel example of desired output

[image]
Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3):

I imagine that should be possible using [runtime mapping](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/#mapping-runtime-mapping); but that would be overly complicated.

I would just create a ClassMap mapping that specified the column names for the properties in question [docs](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/#mapping-name)

```
public sealed class MyClassMap : CsvClassMap<MyClass>
{
    public MyClassMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.DateSection1Finished).Name("NewColumnHeaderName");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, drneel - thanks for the suggestion I'll give it a go. Many thanks Paul